# Problem with labels

Tags: labels, sv-classes

I have a problem with labels using the springer-style svmono. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[graybox,table,envcountchap]{svmono}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\label{chap:test}

\end{document}
```

After running pdflatex two times, I receice an error with the label.

```
\newlabel{chap:test}{{1}{1}}[
                                        None]
```

What am I'm doing wrong here?

Best regrds...

Comment: Hi and welcome. I got these error `! LaTeX Error: File "svmono.cls" not found.` Where did you find the `svmono` class?

Comment: No issues here using TeXLive 2019 (updated within the last week). Could you show the entire contents of the log file you get from this MWE (perhaps first delete the aux and log and then recompile).

Comment: The error message seems incomplete to me (in fact, I don't see *any* error message here—only the context). AFAIK, `\newlabel` in standard LaTeX takes no optional argument (this could be specific behavior of the non-standard class used).